# Docbook stylesheet and tables, FOP error

Tags: apache, apache-fop, docbook

I've never experienced this error since I use Docbook. I've looked it up and found out that this error was fixed earlier in the past (and also I gave a try to do the same steps as it was explained). Unfortunately, I haven't managed to fix it on my own yet.

*Here is the error message that FOP gives:*

> WARNING: The following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet: table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (See position 2:182518)
>   2011.10.19. 11:19:37 org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   SEVERE: Invalid property value encountered in column-width="proportional-column- width(1)": org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyException:
>    file:/c:/fajlok/teszt/book.fo:2:182518: proportional-column-width() function may only be used when fo:table has table-layout="fixed".; property:'column-width' (See position 2:182598)
>   org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyException:
>    file:/c:/fajlok/teszt/book.fo:2:182518: proportional-column-width() function may only be used when fo:table has table-layout="fixed".; property:'column-width'

Basically it notifies me that in FOP hasn't been implemented the table-layout="auto" feature yet.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use the latest snapshot of FOP and also the latest xml stylesheet (1.76.0).

Comment: Issue solved! If you got this issue, you have just to change the 'fop1.extensions' param value to '1' in the fo/param.xsl.

Comment: You should submit the "Issue solved!" comment as an answer (a little later you can accept it). See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm that the warning isn't seen when fop1.extensions is set to "1".

My stylesheet contains

```
<xsl:param name="fop1.extensions" select="1"/>
```

And still I get

```
The following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet: table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (See position 1362:428)
```

I am using fop version 1:1.0.dfsg2-6 (debian sid)